# How to get notification additionaldata(payloadData) that was at AppDelegate' didFinishLunchingWithOptions if the user didn't open the notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, payload, onesignal

I am currently using **OneSignal** for notification service to my app.I really need a help with accessing notification **additionaldata**(payload data) from **AppDelegate** inside **didFinishLunchingWithOption** where OneSignal API can give me like this.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var data : [NSObject : AnyObject]!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let oneSignal = OneSignal(launchOptions: launchOptions, appId: "48755d3d-abc0-4bac-8f71-095729bb3a65") { (message, additionalData, isActive) in
        NSLog("OneSignal Notification opened:\nMessage: %@", message)

        if additionalData != nil {
            NSLog("additionalData: %@", additionalData)
            self.data = additionalData
            print(self.data)
        }
    }
    oneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true)
    return true
}
}
```

but,I can only get the data if user click notification when appear or open it from notification center.So,if user neglect that notification without tapping when appear or without swiping or tapping from notification center,how do i get the additional data?

Actually,I want to store all payload data every time it comes into my device at realm database and fetch the data from my server according to that payload data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use  `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`.

If you have enabled remote notifications background mode most of your notifications will be delivered even if the app is not running in the foreground. The only caveat being that the app must have been launched (since notifications are being pushed the user has done this) and it mustn't have been force-quit by the user.

More info in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) about that specific method.
Or in the ["Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide's"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) notification handling chapter

Comment: Thanks,but,i need to ask you some question.The application is in background.When the notification comes in,the user neglect it.So,how do we get the payload data?I saw that we can only get notification data when user swipe the notification at noti center or click on alert.

Answer (score -1):

You can extract all the payload in did finishLaunching by following method..

Let data = launchOptions.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationUIApplicationLaunchOptionsUIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can get the data only if the user tapped the notification.But,can't when user neglect the notifications or don't tap the notification that was sent.